# Returning variables in Angular JS factories?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, variables, service, factory

I have the following code...

```
spa.factory("linkService", function() {
    var currentLink = null;
    return {currentLink:};
});

var cssController = spa.controller("cssController", function(linkService, currentLink) {
        this.fileName = linkService.currentLink;
});

var navigationController = spa.controller("navigationController", function(linkService, currentLink) {
    this.setLink = function(setValue) {
        linkService.currentLink  = setValue;
    };
    this.checkCurrent = function(checkValue) {
        return linkService.currentLink == checkValue;
    }
});
```

I've created this code from a snippet I wrote in another question, and fixed the things I was told were wrong with my first attempt. That question can be found here. This is a more specific case, and is therefore not a duplicate.

After checking the console, I believe the problem with this script lies in the factory.

The attempted function of the `linkService` factory is to provide a variable, `currentLink` which can be accessed and changed dynamically by more than one controller. The variable inside the factory I believe should be accessed by injecting the factory as a dependency into the controller function, as well as the variable.

What is the issue here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your linkService factory returns an object with the slot 'currentLink' and its value undefined.

You have to return the variable directly or you can return an object which references your variable or you can return an object which includes getter and setters to your variables.

The last variant has the advantage of having a nice interface defined in place.
Your code will be better readable.

```
spa.factory("linkService", function() {
   var currentLink = "/myLink.html";
    /* accessor for currentLink */
    var getLink = function(){
      return currentLink;
    }; 
    return {get: getLink}; // service interface
});
```

--- update

Some more details:

- currentLink is the variable which should be accessed and which is present in the context of the linkService only
- the factory returns the object "{get: getLink}" as the service. So if a controller injects the linkService, it gets this object.
  Using linkService.get(); you can access the variable currentLink.
- getLink is a local function only. It serves as an accessor.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding this. If I understand correctly we're setting an object only to set another object as the value of the first object, and then returning an array where the value is indexed as 'get'. Why can't we just declare the first object and be done with it?

Comment: I added some explanations. 
Does this help?

Comment: I'm sorry for being so brick-headed, but I still don't understand; not even with your new comments. So, currentLink is declared as a variable but is only available withing the scope of linkService. Knowing that, the factory's purpose needs to be that on injection it returns the value on the variable inside it's scope, so that we can access the data outside of the local scope. I don't understand why this can't be accomplished by simply returning the variable. Why do we need the sub function? In addition, even if we solved that problem, there would be no way to save new data.

Comment: If you wont change the state of the variable, you can return it directly too.
BUT: usually you are manipulating the value of the variable. And if you return it directly, you would return the value instead of the reference to the object.

Answer (score 0):

The factory should return objects/methods as such:

```
spa.factory("linkService", function() {
    var linkServiceFactory = {};
    var _currentLink = null;
    linkServiceFactory.currentLink = _currentLink;
    return linkServiceFactory;

});
```

In the controller to inject it with the factory name to get its sub-parts.:

```
 var cssController = spa.controller("cssController", function(linkService) {
            this.fileName = linkService.currentLink;
    });
```

Similarly,

```
var navigationController = spa.controller("navigationController", function(linkService) {
    // other code.
});
```